# Are there any other special case Windows environment variables like PATH?

Tags: c#, windows, environment-variables

Generally in Windows, system-level environment variables are superceded by user-level environment variables with the same name. The PATH environment variable is however a special case. The user-level PATH environment variable is appended to the end of the system-level environment variable.

I use the following C# code to get the process-level environment variable values, taking this special case into account. Note that I can't use the EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process option because this won't take into account any changes since my application started running.

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> GetEnvironmentVariables()
{

    var environmentVariables = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    //get machine environment variables
    IDictionary machineEnvironmentVariables = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables(EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);
    foreach (DictionaryEntry envVar in machineEnvironmentVariables)
    {
        string key = envVar.Key.ToString()
        environmentVariables[key] = envVar.Value.ToString();
    }

    //overwrite with any user environment variables
    IDictionary userEnvironmentVariables = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables(EnvironmentVariableTarget.User);
    foreach (DictionaryEntry envVar in userEnvironmentVariables)
    {
        string key = envVar.Key.ToString();
        if (key.ToLower() == "path" && environmentVariables.ContainsKey(key))
            environmentVariables[key] += envVar.Value.ToString();
        else
            environmentVariables[key] = envVar.Value.ToString();
    }
    return environmentVariables;

}
```

My question is: are there any other special cases which need to be taken into account? Please include a link to documentation backing up your answer.

Comment: I'm not aware of any.  But regardless, you should probably P/Invoke the CreateEnvironmentBlock function rather than trying to reimplement it yourself.

Comment: My code needs to run in a medium trust environment so I can't use p/invoke

Comment: If PATH works like this then possibly PATHEXT might work the same way. I never heard of anyone changing this variable though